# Shopify brooklyn theme slide link not working

Tags: hyperlink, shopify, slide

I am setting up a slide link in my brooklyn theme in the following site:
https://www.syltersunglasses.com/

As you can see, there is a field for the slide link.

However, the link on each slide isn't working.

What could it be?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The slide link field is a link for a button(Button text) in slider, not a link for a complete slider and your button text field seems to be empty. Please type any text in Button text and check whether link is working or not!

Comment: Hello, thanks for clarifying this, how can I do to have the whole slide linked?

Comment: To link a whole slider you have to work on slider liquid file for that please have a look on shopiy liquid templating language and need a idea of creating section in shopify